# Powershell script to count specific files in directories & subdirectories

Tags: powershell, count, get-childitem

I am trying to make a powershell script which will count all the .xml files in directories & subdirectories and list the value + path.

So far I have done the this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:/test -recurse -include *.xml
```

Which is close to what I want but without the actual files names, just the folder paths and counts.

This is what I am getting:

```
>     Directory: C:\test\A_Sub-folder
> Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
> ----                -------------     ------ ----
> -a---        27/11/2015     11:29          0 AA.xml
> 
>     Directory: C:\test 
> Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
> ----                -------------     ------ ----
> -a---        27/11/2015     11:29          0 BB.xml
> -a---        27/11/2015     11:29          0 CC.xml
> -a---        27/11/2015     11:29          0 DD.xml
```

And I'm trying to get this ( or similar):

```
 >  Directory: C:\test\A_Sub-folder
 > 1
 >  Directory: C:\test 
 > 3
```

The plan is to run this script on each root drive (some drives have around 5k .xml files, so I am not sure how this will affect performance.)

Edit:

This works perfectly for subfolders but for some reason it doesn't work under root drive directories (eg. e:/).
I'm trying to exclude \windows and \program files but it doesn't work. Is there any way of excluding root directories in the search?

Script so far:

```
$excludedPaths = @("E:\Windows", "E\Program Files", "E:\Program Files (x86)", "E:\MSSQL", "E:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER");
$pathtocount = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input path to count xml files'
Get-ChildItem -Path $pathtocount -recurse -include *.xml | Where-Object { $excludedPaths -notcontains $_.Directory } | Group-Object -Property Directory | Sort-Object count
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:/test -recurse -filter *.xml | Group-Object -Property Directory
```

And to get a nicer table, you could add `-NoElement` to `Group-Object`.

To exclude some directories, try:

```
$excludedPaths = @("Windows", "Program Files", "Program Files (x86)");
$searchPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory | Where-Object { $excludedPaths -notcontains $_.name }
Get-ChildItem -Path $searchPaths -recurse -filter *.xml | Group-Object -Property Directory
```

**Update:**
According to [Get-ChildItem documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx), `-filter` is more efficient than `-include` when you only filter for one pattern. (If you filter for more patterns, `-filter` doesn't work and you have to use `-include`)

For excluding whole subtrees:

- `-exclude` doesn't work, because it is applied to each file, it doesn't prune the whole tree, and it seems the filter is only matched to the filename, not the directory
- your `Where-Object` doesn't work because `$_.Directory` returns nothing (not sure why, I haven't found any documentation)
- Even if looking at another property (`$_.FullName` seems to do what you intend), this would only remove the directory itself, not paths starting with the directory. You would need to do a string-prefix-match (using -imatch or -ilike) against each string in the filter-set

Comment: Yours was better than mine.  :)

Comment: @Nate Don't be discouraged, you made a good effort in your answer, it just wasn't quite right. Keep trying, it's good to see newer people posting answers! :) Plus, it's amazing how much you can learn just figuring out other people's issues. Sometimes it leads to great new perspectives on problems and helps solve issues you come across on your own.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I wanted! Cheers guys :)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Psh, I ain't scrrd.  :P

Comment: @Rolf Rander This works perfectly for subfolders but for some reason it doesn't work under root drive directories (eg. e:/). Is it a powershell bug? See OP.

Comment: What doesn't work? Don't you get any results, or is it the filtering of certain directories?

Comment: I do get results, but with the excluded directories specified in $excludedPaths (windows, program files, etc.). This is when I run this under e:\ or c:\ drive. If I run this in c:\test it does excludes the specified directories.

Comment: Of course; running a recursive search for files under c:\test won't find any files in c:\windows. I believe your results is because of your trouble filtering results and not a specific feature of running the script from root.

Comment: I'm running the recursive search under 'c:\' excluding 'c:\windows' directory but I still get 'c:\windows' in my results.

Comment: As I have outlined in the update to my answer, filtering (pruning) subtrees from Get-ChildItem turns out to be quite complicated, it doesn't work how one would think it does, and it doesn't give you any speedup (all subdirectories are searched anyway). I think specifying which directories you want to search is easier than specifying which to exclude.

Comment: what about not to include sub-directories in counting?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer you want to count the number of xml-files in a directory without recursing?

Comment: i want to count the number of xml files without counting xml files inside sub directories

Comment: @rickyProgrammer just remove the "recurse"-flag

Comment: i did, and just make -File -include *.txt but the result is 0 count.

Comment: please see this and give advice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916917/powershell-script-to-count-txt-files-only-in-a-directory