# Powershell Script to count .txt files only in a directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

My goal is to send email to some users to notify about the **current count of the  files** inside some folder directories.

I need to count files only with .txt extensions and exclude folders and files inside this.

please see below illustration

**U:\TESTING\Main Folder**

[image: Testing Main Folder Image]

**U:\TESTING\Main Folder\Sub Folder 1**

[image: Testing Sub Folder 1 Image]

**U:\TESTING\Main Folder\Sub Folder 2**

[image: Testing Sub Folder 2 Image]

**output result should look somehting like this**

[image: Example output table]

**Main Folder row should be 1 only, but it also includes the sub folders 1 and 2 and the txt files inside those.**

**Here's the part of the code that counts the total files**

```
$total = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -File -Include *.txt |Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object{$_.Count}
```

When I remove -Recurse in this line, the result becomes **0** for total column

```
 $total = Get-ChildItem $path  -File -Include *.txt |Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object{$_.Count}
```

Comment: Replace `-recurse` with `-file`.

Comment: I have edited the whole content..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following workaround

1. by using -filter instead of -include

just remove the -recurse to exclude subdirectories files in counting
and use -filter instead of -include

```
$path = "D:\LIVE"

 $total = Get-ChildItem $path  -File -filter *.txt |Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object{$_.Count}
```

2. using get-Item instead of Get-ChildItem with -include

-Filter is limited to using one paramter, so if you want to use -include to use as many searching parameter as you can, use Get-Item instead of get-childItem

just add * (when no path is declared) or * appending to the existing path

```
$path = "D:\LIVE\*"

 $total = Get-Item $path -include *.txt, *.xml  |Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object{$_.Count}
```

Comment: Yes, without `-Recurse` `-Include` unfortunately doesn't work as expected - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304. Two asides: `Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime}` is a no-op, because every file by definition has a (non-null) value in `.LastWriteItem`, which, when coerced to a Boolean, evaluates to `$true`. Instead of `ForEach-Object{$_.Count}`, you can just use `( ... | Measure-Object).Count`.

Comment: my problem with -filter it is limited to one parameter only... when i add a parameter to search, it is having an exception error

Comment: So I am trying to still use -include, you mentioned there to use Get-Item instead of Get-ChildItem, when i did, I am having this error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument